# Removing a Row in Python DataFrame - No unique index

Tags: pandas

I'm having trouble removing a single from the dataset. Here's my dataset:

| Name | Class | Score | School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Physics | 85 | School1 |
| Ryan | Biology | 70 | School2 |
| Helen | Biology | 90 | School1 |
| Bob | Math | 78 | School1 |
| Ryan | Biology | 70 | School2 |

As a DataFrame:

```
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Ryan', 'Helen', 'Bob', 'Ryan'],
    'Class': ['Physics', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Math', 'Biology'],
    'Score': [85, 70, 90, 78, 70],
    'School': ['School1', 'School2', 'School1', 'School1', 'School2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to remove Helen from my original dataframe. I can't use .drop(index='School1') because there are multiple rows have 'School1' as index. Can anyone give me some advice?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to select all columns that do not contain the name `Helen`:

```py
df = df.loc[df["Name"] != "Helen", :]
```

If you have multiple names you want to filter out, you can also do this:

```py
names_to_remove = ["Alice", "Helen"]
df = df.loc[~df["Name"].isin(names_to_remove), :]
```

Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).